# Are hyperbolic spaces actually better for embedding trees than Euclidean spaces?

Tags: graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, trees, metric-embeddings

There is a folklore in the empirical computer-science literature that, given a tree $(X,d)$, one can find a bi-Lipschitz embedding into a hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$ and that $n$ is "much smaller" than the smallest dimension of a Euclidean space in which $(X,d)$ can be bi-Lipschitz embedded with similar distortion.

**Question A:** Is there any theoretical grounding to this claim?  Namely, can one prove that $(X,d)$ *(where $\# X = n\in\mathbb{N}_+$)* admits a bi-Lipschitz embedding into some $\mathbb{H}^n$ with:

- distortion strictly less that $O(\log(n))$
- $n<O(\log^2n)$?

**! Edit - (Following Discussion of YCor, WillSawin, and TomTheQuant):** *What can be said if $s=1$ in Equation (1)?*

**Question B (Converse):**  For every $n\in \mathbb{N}_+$ and every $D>0$ does there exist a *finite metric space* $(X,d)$, which don't admit a bi-Lipschitz (resp. possibly [uniform embedding](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101412/uniform-embedding-into-euclidean-space)) into $\mathbb{H}^n$ with distortion at-most $D$?

**Relevant Definition (For completeness)**

A bi-Lipschitz embedding $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{H}^n$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ into $\mathbb{H}^n$ with distortion $D>0$ is a Lipschitz homeomorphism $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{H}^n$ Lipschitz inverse $f^{-1}$ such that there is some $s>0$ satisfying
$$
sd(x_1,x_2) \leq d_{\mathbb{H}^n}(f(x_1),f(x_2)) \leq sDd(x_1,x_2)
\qquad (1)
$$
for every $x_1,x_2\in X$.  Here, $d_{\mathbb{H}^n}$ is the usual geodesic distance on the $n$-dimensional hyperbolic space.

**Some Relevant posts:**

*Hyperbolic embeddings*

- [References to embedding into hyperbolic spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215550/embedding-graphs-into-hyperbolic-spaces?rq=1)
- [Representability of finite metric spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12394/representability-of-finite-metric-spaces?rq=1)

*Flat Embeddings*

- [Problem with embedding expanders into "flat" spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146679/embedding-expanders-in-cat0-spaces?rq=1)
- [Characterizing finite metric spaces which embed into Euclidean space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297654/a-characterization-of-metric-spaces-admitting-a-bi-lipschitz-embedding-into-a-hi/297761#297761)

*Uniform Embeddings*

- [Notes on coarse and uniform embeddings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03109)

Comment: Are you implicitly assuming that $X$ is finite? Infinite trees (of bounded valency) can be bilipschitz-embedded into the hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^2$, but not into any Euclidean (or even Hilbert) space.

Comment: @YCor Yes I was implicitly assuming finiteness; but I'm interested in both situations.

Comment: @YCor Do you have a reference for those two results you mention?

Comment: That infinite bushy trees (bushy= of valency $\ge 3$ at every vertex) can't be embedded bilipschitz into Hilbert spaces is a result of Bourgain in the 80s (that they can't be embedded bilipschitz or even uniformly into Euclidean spaces just follows from growth conditions).

Comment: For embedding a bilipschitz tree of constant valency $\ge 3$ into the hyperbolic plane, there are plenty of ways. I don't know what is the first reference. One can produce this with actions of free groups; in this way the earliest reference is possibly Schottky. One can also inscribe such trees in regular tilings.

Comment: But then are there finite metric spaces for which this is impossible?

Comment: A finite metric space can trivially be embedded bilipschitz into any infinite space (take any injective map). The issue is only to do  it with good constants.

Comment: I mean, aren't there finite metric spaces which don't admit `good' low distortion (bi-Lipschitz embedding with small distortion into low-dimensional Hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$ for small $n$)?

Comment: @YCor I clarified this (opposite point) in the question itself.

Comment: Possibly expanders are good candidates, but I'm not familiar enough with this field to be sure. Possibly more plainly, "Euclidean pieces" (e.g., a copy of the $n$-ball in $\mathbf{Z}^2$) can't also be embedded with small distortion in $H^d$ (regardless of $d$).

Comment: @YCor I also was thinking the same (About expanders being a good candidate).  Do you have a reference for this last statement (I don't know this notion).

Comment: @YCor By the definition given in the question, we are allowed to shrink the metric by a scalar factor $s$, which may be arbitrarily small. Taking $s$ small enough, we should be able to embed the $n$-ball in $\mathbb Z^2$ with arbitrarily small distortion by using the local linearity of hyperbolic space.

Comment: @WillSawin Oh, yes indeed.

Comment: And actually that we can rescale (this time, to large scale) makes it quite immediate that every finite (weighted) tree can be embedded with distortion $\le 1+\varepsilon$ into the hyperbolic plane (since it embeds isometrically into the asymptotic cone of $H^2$ which is a real tree).

Comment: Ah, but if we force $s=1$ then are such embeddings still obvious (for the tree metric case, not the converse)?

Comment: @TomTheQuant Yes, this should prevent Will Sawin + YCor's rescaling trickery; since its not clear if we can locally embed $(X,d)$ into $\mathbb{Z}^2$ in the tangent space of some point in $\mathbb{H}^2$.

Comment: @YCor Which is the Schottky article you are referring to?

Comment: I assume that the trees in this question have at most countably many vertices and edges. Obviously no tree with more than continuum many vertices can be embedded in any hyperbolic n-space. (The case of a tree with exactly continuum many vertices is probably excluded since two distinct vertices of such a tree must come arbitrarily close to each other in the embedding.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure if the following paper answers your question. The abstract suggests so, but it is written in a computer science style that is less transparent to me in terms of stating a precise theorem. Also: (a) I am not an expert, (b) I am confused by the way that $n$ seems to play two different roles in your question, and (c) I doubt if it is the earliest answer to your question, if indeed it does answer it.

[Low Distortion Delaunay Embedding of Trees in Hyperbolic Plane by Rik Sarkar](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rsarkar/papers/HyperbolicDelaunayFull.pdf)

> Abstract. **This paper considers the problem of embedding trees into the
> hyperbolic plane.** We show that any tree can be realized as the
> Delaunay graph of its embedded vertices. **Particularly, a weighted tree
> can be embedded such that the weight on each edge is realized as the
> hyperbolic distance between its embedded vertices.** Thus the embedding
> preserves the metric information of the tree along with its topology.
> **Further, the distance distortion between non adjacent vertices can be
> made arbitrarily small – less than a $(1+\epsilon)$ factor for any given $\epsilon$.**
> Existing results on low distortion of embedding discrete metrics into
> trees carry over to hyperbolic metric through this result. The
> Delaunay character implies useful properties such as guaranteed greedy
> routing and realization as minimum spanning trees.

(bolding is mine.)

Comment: @Carl_Petterson Regardless of the quality of the paper, I think the key claim is correct and answers your first question - we can embed any finite tree into the hyperbolic plane with distortion $D = 1+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$, by taking $s$ sufficiently large (proportional to $(1+\epsilon)/\epsilon)$. (I was in fact planning to type a (trivial) proof of this before seeing this answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a trivial example for question B (in the $s=1$ case):

The discrete metric space on $N$ points with distance 1 between every two distinct points has the minimal distortion of an embedding into $\mathbb H^n$ going to $\infty$  as $N$ goes to $\infty$ with respect to $n$.

Indeed, for an embedding of distortion $D$, any two points in the embedding must have distance at least $1$, so the balls of radius $1/2$ around these points must be disjoint.  But every two points have distance at most $D$, so the balls of radius $1/2$ around these points must be contained in the ball of radius $D+1/2$ around one point.

Thus, for an embedding to exist, the volume of the ball of radius $D+1/2$ must be at least $N$ times the volume of the ball of radius $1/2$.

Thus $D$ must go to $\infty$ if $N$ goes to $\infty$ with fixed $n$.

Comment: Do you think this type of argument can be generalized to @A_K's setting, or is it exclusive to hyperbolic space?

Comment: @Carl_Petterson We need a lower bound for the volume of small balls and an upper bound for the volume of large balls. This should exist in a Riemannian manifold with sectional curvature bounded above and below under mild conditions (a lower bound on the injectivity radius). I don't think this strategy can be generalized to spaces of Markov type.